# Allocation fails only on release

Tags: c, console, windows-10, codeblocks

When debugging the program works how it's supposed to. When running the release version, it tells me I have not enough space. Why is this happening and how can I make it run in the release exe?

I found some other article, but I don't get where the similarities are.
[C malloc weird behavior on debug/release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078417/c-malloc-weird-behavior-on-debug-release)

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define AMOUNT  100000                              // amount of random numbers
#define RANDOM  (rand() & 0x1F) + (rand() << 16)    // 32 bit random number

struct sNumStruct {
    unsigned int uiNum;             // number
    struct sNumStruct *pNext;       // next
    struct sNumStruct *pPrev;       // previous
};

int main()
{
    /// initializing
    srand(time(NULL));              // rand() initializer
    unsigned int i = 0;             // counter
    struct sNumStruct * pNumbers;   // pointer to number structure
    struct sNumStruct * pStart;     // pointer to start of list
    struct sNumStruct * pLast;      // pointer to end of list

    /// random number generation
    printf("Generating %d random numbers ...\n", AMOUNT);

    pStart = (struct sNumStruct*)malloc(sizeof(struct sNumStruct*));    // allocating memory for first element
    if(pStart == NULL)              // allocation failed?
    {
        perror("-1");               // print error -1
        return -1;
    }
    pStart->pNext = NULL;           // next element is NULL
    pStart->pPrev = NULL;           // prev element is NULL

    pNumbers = pStart;              // point to number structure
    pNumbers->uiNum = RANDOM;       // get random number

    for(i = 0; i < AMOUNT; i++)     // repeat AMOUNT times
    {
        printf("%d,", i);           // <---------- DEBUG
        pNumbers->pNext = (struct sNumStruct*)malloc(sizeof(struct sNumStruct*));   // allocating memory for next element
        if(pNumbers->pNext == NULL) // allocation failed?
        {
            perror("-2");           // print error -2
            return -2;
        }
        (pNumbers->pNext)->pPrev = pNumbers;    // current element is previous from next
        pNumbers = pNumbers->pNext;             // next element
        pNumbers->uiNum = RANDOM;               // random number
        pNumbers->pNext = NULL;                 // next element is NULL
    }
    pLast = pNumbers;

    printf("\n... done generating numbers\n");

    // sort(&pNumbers);

    return 0;
}
```

The output I'm getting is:
"Generating 100000 random numbers ...
0,1,-2: Not enough space

Process returned -2 (0xFFFFFFFE)"

the "0,1," are how many elements it has allocated. so it fails on the first "next element" allocation.
"-2" confirms the statement above

expected to see:
"Generating 100000 random numbers ...
0,1, ....(not gonna type all numbers)... 99998,99999,
... ... done generating numbers

Process returned 0"

Comment: Maybe you could add some code to free your pointers after using them. This might give the debug library a chance to detect heap corruption after using more space than you allocated for your struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this :

`pStart = (struct sNumStruct*)malloc(sizeof(struct sNumStruct*));`

You are allocating the sizeof a pointer, which is probably 8bytes if you are on a 64bits system. 
You should rather use :

`pStart = (struct sNumStruct*)malloc(sizeof(struct sNumStruct));` (without the pointer)

which will allocate the size needed for your struct.

Maybe this might help ?

Comment: Oh yea! I remember... Thanks alot! :)